# DatePicker ng-Bootstrap dropdown for range datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap to create two calendars and select a given range from them.
In their documentation they have an example of it, but the calendar doesn't appear on a dropdown.

So I did it using something like this :

```
    <form class="form-inline">
  <div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select a range" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)"
        [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
      <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day" [class.focused]="focused" [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
    [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)" (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date" (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

The issue here is that when I click on a date it automatically displays it on the value of the input and I want both dates ( the end Date and the start Date )to display there .
And then based off these two dates, I need to filter a table.

But the fromDate and the toDate here, are of type NgbDateStruct, and I need them to be a date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
Here's how I filter:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let row of allData| filterPipe: fromDate:toDate">
```

And then on the filterPipe I have this function:

```
value=value.filter(item=>moment(item.setDate).isBetween(fromDate,toDate));
```

The issue is that fromDate and toDate is an object of type NgbDateStruct, and that both those values don't show up on my

How do I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use  a function tthat return a string like "yyyy-MM-dd" and have as argument a variable type NgbDateStructure. create two auxiliar variables. In the function onChangeDate, change the value of the two auxiliar variables calling the before function. Filter using this two variables

Comment: @ user9047579 did you get this figured out?